# How to use a CFS_Config textfile to create path directories to auto generate text files in python?

Tags: python, directory, filepath

Below is the data in CFS_Config.txt. What this textfile does is to know where the documents have stored and to avoid hardcodes in the program. For instance, if the program is moved to other environment, we only need to change the directory paths in the CFS_Config.txt file.

```
Folder Path = ../dataprep/source_documents
ED Notes name = ED Notes
ED Notes output = ../dataprep/ED_Notes
```

This below codes in a python file what it actually does is to read configuration from the CFS_Config.txt mentioned earlier and also to do an auto generated textfile. 
The problem encountered is that they tell me the ../dataprep/ED_Notes path was not found. Please do take a look at the codes if need more codes I will try my best to provide, thanks!!! :((

```
from preprocessing import ednotes_extractor
import os

def read_config():

    # open existing file to read configuration
    cfs_config_txt = open("..\CFS_Config.txt", "r")

    file_list = []
    root_dir = ""
    ednotes_name = ""
    ednotes_output = ""

    for line in cfs_config_txt:
        file_list.append(line)

    if "Folder Path = " in file_list[0]:
        root_dir = str(file_list[0])
        root_dir = root_dir.replace("Folder Path = ", "")
        root_dir = root_dir.replace("\n", "")

    if "ED Notes name = " in file_list[1]:
        ednotes_name = str(file_list[1])
        ednotes_name =  ednotes_name.replace("ED Notes name = ", "")
        ednotes_name =  ednotes_name.replace("\n", "")

    if "ED Notes output = " in file_list[2]:
        ednotes_output = str(file_list[2])
        ednotes_output = ednotes_output.replace("ED Notes output = ", "")
        ednotes_output = ednotes_output + ".txt"
        ednotes_output = ednotes_output.replace("\n", "")

    return root_dir, ednotes_name, ednotes_output



def convert_txt(choices):

    root_dir, ednotes_name, ednotes_output = read_config()

    if(choices == 1):

        # open new file to write string data textfile
        text_file = open(ednotes_output, 'w', encoding='utf-8')
        text_file.write("cat_id|content\n")

        for filename in os.listdir(root_dir):
            source_directory = root_dir + '/' + filename
            arr = ednotes_extractor.get_ednotes(source_directory)

            # open existing file to append the items in the array to the previously written textfile
            text_file = open(ednotes_output, 'a', encoding='utf-8')
            for item in arr:
                text_file.write("%s\n" % item)


    elif(choices==2):
        print("Hi")
```